# R: shade area between a curve and a circle

Tags: r, plot, polygon

I have a plot in which I draw a circle over the standard normal pdf. See below the lines used to draw this figure. The figure is ok, but my problem is: How to shade the areas A, B, C, D, E and F? I know I have to find the points of intersection but I don't know how to find them. Suggestions will be welcome.

```
library(plotrix)

x   <-  seq(-3.0, 3.0, 0.01)
fy  <-  dnorm(x)
fy  <-  fy / max(fy)

plot(x, fy, ylim = c(-1, 1), col = "white", lwd = 1.5, xlim = c(-3, 3), lty = 1)

draw.circle(0.0, 0.0, 2.00,  border = 'blue', lty = 1, lwd = 0.8)

lines(x, fy, type = 'l', ylim = c(-1,1), col = 'red', )
lines(x,-fy, type = 'l', ylim = c(-1,1), col = 'red')

text( 0.0, 0.90, "A"); text( 0.0,-0.90, "B")
text(-1.8, 0.25, "C"); text( 1.8, 0.25, "D")
text(-1.8,-0.25, "E"); text( 1.8,-0.25, "F")
```

[image: circ + normal pdf]

Comment: Seems that draw.circle draws a circle independent of the y scale. You should better use draw.ellipse to preserve proportions no regards of the

Comment: C and D are the same area as are E and F. How do you want the space within the circle above the normal density curve shaded? Also adding asp=1 to the plot command will make the x and y scales the same in your plot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way how to do it. First, I had to modify your figure a bit because your circle is not really a circle. As mentioned in the comments, the `draw.circle` function draws something that always looks like a circle, independent of the y axis scale. So in terms of your plot coordinates your circle is actually an ellipse. To find the intersections, this has to be dealt with: either we work with an ellipse or stretch the normal distribution *y* range so that it really extends above the circle. Since your question is about a circle, I went with the latter.

I wasn't able to find the intersections analytically (I wonder if this can be done?) so I did it numerically, which is not too complicated. You just define a function which you want to minimize over a specified interval and use `optimize()` to find the location of the minimum. Here, the function is just the difference between *y* coordinates of the circle and the normal distribution curve. Where this function (`y_diff()`) is zero is our intersection. I only did this in the first quadrant because the rest is symmetric:

```r
## Computes circle y coordinates (only upper half circle)
f_circle <- function(x, r=2) ifelse(abs(x) <= r, sqrt(r^2 - x^2), NA)
## Multiplies normal distribution by a constant
f_norm <- function(x, mult=6.8) dnorm(x) * mult
  
## Y difference between the two functions used to find
#    the intersection points
y_diff <- function(x) abs(f_circle(x) - f_norm(x))

# x coordinates of the two intersects between the circle and normal
#   distributino curve in the first quadrant
x.inter <- c(optimize(y_diff, c(0, 1))$minimum,
             optimize(y_diff, c(1.5, 2))$minimum)
```

Then I created a function which computes *x* and *y* coordinates of polygons delimiting a specified area of interest and used it to compute coordinates of all the six polygons:

```r
## Computes x and y coordinates of polygons between the circle and normal 
#   distribution curve
#
#  get.peak      Should normal curve peak area be returned? 
#    TRUE: areas A, B; FALSE: C, D, E, F
#  x.neg, y.neg  their combination gives the quadrant of interest
#
area_between <- function(get.peak=T, x.neg=F, y.neg=F, step=.01) {
  
  x.lim <- 'if'(get.peak,
                x.inter[1] * c(-1, 1),
                sort(x.inter * (-1)^x.neg))
  x <- seq(x.lim[1], x.lim[2], by=step)
  
  data.frame(x=c(x, rev(x)),
             y=c(f_circle(x), f_norm(rev(x))) * (-1)^y.neg)
}
  
# definitions of the areas in terms of the parameters of area_between()
area.pxy <- rbind(A = c(T, NA, F),
                  B = c(T, NA, T),
                  C = c(F,  T, F),
                  D = c(F,  F, F),
                  E = c(F,  T, T),
                  F = c(F,  F, T))
# areas' x,y coordinates
area.xy <- mapply(area_between, 
                  area.pxy[, 1], area.pxy[, 2], area.pxy[, 3], 
                  SIMPLIFY=F)
```

And now we just draw it:

```r
# asp=1 so that the y/x aspect ratio is 1
plot(0, 0, ylim=c(-1, 1)*2.7, asp=1, type='n', xlab='x', ylab='y')
x <- seq(-3, 3, .01)

# draw the areas one by one
for (i in seq_along(area.xy)) {
  
  xy <- area.xy[[i]]
  polygon(xy, col=i, border=NA)
  text(mean(xy$x), mean(xy$y), names(area.xy)[i], col='white', font=2)
}

# draw circle
suppressWarnings(  # there are NAs which would cause warnings
  lines(c(x, rev(x)), c(f_circle(x), -f_circle(x)), col='blue')
)
# draw normal distributions
lines(x, f_norm(x), col='red')
lines(x, -f_norm(x), col='red')
```

[image: Shaded areas]